# Assert attribute on mock instance was accessed

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How can I assert that an attribute on a [`Mock`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) and/or a [`MagicMock`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) was accessed?

For example,

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def foo(x):
    a = x.value

m = MagicMock()
foo(m)
m.attr_accessed('value')    # method that does not exist but I wish did; should return True
```

What is an actual way to check that `foo` attempted to access `m.value`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use PropertyMock as described [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock#unittest.mock.PropertyMock).

e.g.,

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, PropertyMock

def foo(x):
    a = x.value

m = MagicMock()
p = PropertyMock()
type(m).value = p
foo(m)
p.assert_called_once_with()
```